# Best way to convert a itertools.filterfalse object to a list

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have been searching high and low for insight into itertools.filterfalse without much luck for my particular questions.

Here is the scenario: I have a set of 48 objects, and I have used itertools.combinations to generate all 9-object combinations from this set.

Question 1: How do I count the number of items in this itertools.combinations object without converting it to a list? The itertools docs provides the formula for this (something on the order of 2.1 billion combinations), but I'm curious to know if there is any built in method to return the value.

After generating these combinations of 48-choose-9, I filtered them using the itertools.filterfalse function. To give you a sense of how stringent this filter is, when I do the same procedure on 33-choose-7 combinations of similar objects, only 28 remain. So, I'm expecting a similarly low number of values when I do 48-choose-9.

The script completes in a matter of seconds for 48-choose-9, and filterfalse returns the filtered combinations into a variable:

```py
valid_combinations = itertools.filterfalse(
    lambda combination: set([action for tile in combination for action in tile])
    != set(total_actions),
    all_combinations,
)
```

`valid_combinations` should be a short list, but my computer runs loudly for several minutes without returning anything when I try:

```py
valid_combinations = list(valid_combinations)
```

Question 2: How do I count the number of items in an itertools.filterfalse object to confirm that it is indeed a manageable number?

Question 3: How do I get the contents of my itertools.filterfalse object validCombinations without converting to a list?

Question 4: Is there a better alternative for filtering an itertools.combinations object of this size?

Thanks for any insights you can send my way!

Comment: _Question 2: How do I count the number of items in an itertools.filterfalse object to confirm that it is indeed a manageable number?_ That would depend on the filtering condition, right? _Question 3: How do I get the contents of my itertools.filterfalse object validCombinations without converting to a list?_ You can iterate over it directly, although seeing as how you wrote _my computer runs loudly for several minutes without returning anything_, I'm not sure it will make much of a difference.

Comment: _Question 4: Is there a better alternative for filtering an itertools.combinations object of this size?_ I don't think you'll find much better for this exact algorithm/method on the **programming side** of things.

Comment: I seem to detect some confusion in your question about what an iterator is. When you've assigned the iterator to a variable, it hasn't computed a single element yet. It just contains the *instructions* for going through all the combinations and returning the ones that satisfy your condition. So it's not surprising that the `list(...)` call takes some time. It's the actual meat of the thing. Just wait for it to finish; there is no way around it. I would recommend using something like `tqdm` to find out how fast it's iterating. If it's too slow, look into parallelising (e.g., `p_tqdm`).

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I read further last night, and realized I had misunderstood the iterator concept (and generator concept for that matter). @Seb your explanation was very helpful in clarifying it.

Comment: @AMD it's a bit of a Catch 22... if I knew how many results the filtering condition left, I wouldn't need to run the filtering analysis to count them! I thought I had found a way to cheat the system and run it much faster (similar to when I discovered the Counter object), but it seems I've just stumbled upon an inescapably large job. Thanks for the help!